# how to sort a complex list by require order?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a following list:

```
list1 = [
         ['AC', '1'], ['AF', '0.167'], ['AN', '6'],['CAD', '2.741'], ['Bas', '-2.542'], 
         ['CAD', '1.718'], ['AC', '6'],['AN', '6'],['1000g', '0.9998']
        ]
```

In this list, it treat first element that in sublist as a key (eg, AC,AF...), second element that in sublist as value(eg, 1,0.167...)

Some of sublists are exactly as the same (eg, ['AN', '6']), some of them have same key(eg, AC) or same value.

I want to sort this list as requirement,1.  sort by key first(number first (1000g is the first one), then sort alphabetical order, A,B, C), 2. if they have same key, which one appears first comes first(eg, ['CAD', '2.741'] then ['CAD', '1.718'], even though values may not numbers, it still needs to follow the 2nd requirement)

I tried to use `list1.sort()`, but can not achieve the 2nd requirement, it always return smaller number(value) first

the list1 after sort should like this:

```
list1_sorted = [
    ['1000g', '0.9998'], ['AC', '1'],  ['AC', '6'], ['AF', '0.167'], 
    ['AN', '6'],['AN', '6'],['Bas', '-2.542'], ['CAD', '2.741'],  ['CAD', '1.718']
            ]
```

Thanks, any ideas?
if you believe you need more clarification, just comment.

Comment: How can `['AC', '1']` come first. It should be `['AC', '6']` first right?

Comment: no, because ['AC', '1'] in front of ['AC', '6']. so ['AC', '1'] comes first Similarly,  ['CAD', '2.741'] comes first because ['CAD', '2.741'] is front of ['CAD', '1.718']

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.index` to sort them:

```
list1 = [
    ['AC', '1'], ['AF', '0.167'], ['AN', '6'], ['CAD', '2.741'], ['Bas', '-2.542'],
    ['CAD', '1.718'], ['AC', '6'], ['AN', '6'], ['1000g', '0.9998']
]

print(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: (x[0], list1.index(x))))

# [['1000g', '0.9998'], ['AC', '1'], ['AC', '6'], ['AF', '0.167'], ['AN', '6'], ['AN', '6'], ['Bas', '-2.542'], ['CAD', '2.741'], ['CAD', '1.718']]
```